# Change onclick of an image

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an html img

```
<img id="btnViewSpec" alt="View Spec Sheet"src="/images/viewspec.jpg" style="cursor: pointer;" />
```

I need to alter the onclick to target different aspx pages based on what's read from the database. Something like:

```
If DBRead("Keywords").ToString.Contains("glove") Then
    Me.btnViewSpec.Attributes.Add("onclick", ("window.open('/SpecSheet/DisplayPDF.aspx?pa=/SpecSheet/GloveSpec.aspx?pid=" & intProductId & "','wnEmailInfo', 'menubar=no,width=820,height=500,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,status=yes')"))
Else
    Me.btnViewSpec.Attributes.Add("onclick", ("window.open('/SpecSheet/DisplayPDF.aspx?pa=/SpecSheet/ClothingSpec.aspx?pid=" & intProductId & "','wnEmailInfo', 'menubar=no,width=820,height=500,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,status=yes')"))
End If
```

Problem is I can't get the code behind to recognize the image. I tried to register it in the designer code with `Protected WithEvents btnViewSpec As HtmlImage` but no luck. I guess I just don't fully understand the issue or what gets registered in the designer code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `runat="server"` to the image tag and you will have access to the control

Comment: That gives me a "server tag not well formed error" any other suggestions?

Comment: looks like you need space between alt and src attributes

Comment: Always the simple stuff. Thank you sir.